# How to close Dialog Box that's not going away

Tags: reactjs

When clicked, the close option won't close the dialog box, and I don't understand why. I did check a few solutions, but those didn't work. I would like to know what I need to do to fix this. The box loads just fine. The screenshot of the box and the code are below:

[image]

The code:

```
const AdvanceFilterScreen = () => {
    ........
    ........
    const [districtDialogOpen, setDistrictDialogOpen] = useState(false);

    const openDialog = () => {
        setDistrictDialogOpen(prev => !prev)
    };

    const closeDialog = () => {
        setDistrictDialogOpen(prev => !prev)
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {district ? <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={closeDialog}>
                <DialogTitle className="districtOverview">{"District Overview"}</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <div className="overAll">
                        <DistrictTable district={district} setFilterButtonValue={setFilterButtonValue} ></DistrictTable>
                    </div>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <div className="closeButton" onClick={closeDialog}>Close</div>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
                : <FilterSearchButton name={name} category={category} district={district} status={status} serialNumber={serialNumber} setFilterButtonValue={setFilterButtonValue}></FilterSearchButton>}
        </div>
    );

};

export default AdvanceFilterScreen;
```

PS: The idea is to show the dialog box every time the By District option is clicked and a value is selected. If you notice the snip closely, you'll see that behind the dialog box is a dropdown that has Kolkata selected in it as its value. This dropdown appears only when the By District option is clicked

Answer (score 2):

Your condition to open the dialog has issue, just use this:

```
{districtDialogOpen ? <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={closeDialog}>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're displaying the dialog whenever `district` has a truthy value, and you're not using your `districtDialogOpen` state value anywhere.

Change this line:

`{district ? <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={closeDialog}>`

to:

`{districtDialogOpen ? <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={closeDialog}>`

...and you should be good.

Comment: district is a separate hook that has nothing to do with the Dialog Box. The idea is to show the dialog box every time the By District option is clicked and a value is selected. If you notice the snip again, you'll see that behind the dialog box is a dropdown that has Kolkata selected in it as its value. This dropdown appears only when the By District option is clicked

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning this in the initial question.